# What is the best way to require_once?

Tags: joomla-3.4, best-practices

**METHOD 1**

Hard coding the directory separator

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.'/models/fields/courselist.php';
```

**METHOD 2**

Soft code the directory separator

```
if(!defined('DS')){
  define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

require_once JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'models'.DS.'fields'.DS.'courselist.php';
```

Comment: Modern PHP versions works fine with "/" on both Windows and Linux.. so your method 1 would be sufficient..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there's any difference in speed, but I find the first method easier to read. The reason to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is to stay platform independent. Your second example:

```
'models'.DS.'fields'.DS.'courselist.php'
```

would render like this on on Windows:

```
models\fields\courselist.php
```

and like this on most other systems:

```
models/fields/courselist.php
```

However, Windows is just as happy with a forward slash `/` as directory separator and will not complain.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  When I use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` for a javascirpt file then mozilla firefox (on my localhost) throws `The requested URL was not found on this server`.  I believe it is better hard code the `/` instead of platform specific.

Comment: Another reason to hard code the `/`. But maybe someone has a good reason to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`? Only reason I can think of is when exploding a path that the system gives you.

Answer (score 6):

Joomla got rid of the DS constant with Joomla 3. It's no longer needed in most cases since PHP works fine with a forward slash even on Windows.

So don't use it.